# I cannot upgrade to 12.10 because of graphic-card, Radeon HD 3450

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, ati, 12.10, radeon

I wonder what has happened. I have Ubuntu 12.04 and Ati Radeon HD 3450 and that has supported 3D, now suddenly it does not accept my graphic-card.

I really would like to know what to do?

Should I buy a new graphic card or is there a way to use my graphic-card on 12.10? And if so what is there a graphic-card I should buy?

My Ati is functioning with 3D, on 12.04 I don't understand why it will not upgrade to 12.10.

Comment: I don't understand when you say that Quantal isn't accepting your GC. How's it happening?

Answer (score 2):

Follow this guide http://www.unixmen.com/ubuntu-12-10-and-amd-catalyst-problem-solved/. It solved my problem with HD 4850 I used the Tomasz Makarewicz Repository

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

As it says here:

[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers/129200#129200)

I have the same problem. Or you downgrade Xorg server version to 1.12, or wait until there is some version of the drivers that support Xorg server version 1.13.

Hope this helps.

Correction: I've been told that downgrading to Xorg 1.12 is not an alternative, in this case, because it will break Unity.