# Ubuntu 12.10 can't boot because of wireless adapter?

Tags: wireless, boot, bluetooth

I have a Toshiba L650 Notebook, and I'm trying to boot Ubuntu 12.10 from USB. It works fine on PC, but on my Toshiba it freezes at the Ubuntu loading screen. Right before the freeze, Ubuntu turns my wireless adapters (wifi and bluetooth) on.
Anyone has any idea, how to solve this?

Thank you.

BrainiaC

Comment: I had a problem with my network driver causing kernel panic on a 64-bit system. Maybe this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/408116/ralink-usb-wifi-completely-locks-up-system/455483#455483) will help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's because of wireless apdator. I suspect the culprit is the graphic card and xorg.
I'd like to give you a link. [I cannot upgrade to 12.10 because of graphic-card, Radeon HD 3450](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209762/i-cannot-upgrade-to-12-10-because-of-graphic-card-radeon-hd-3450/211040#211040)